# Nested if statements with 4 if

Tags: shell-script

Hi friends could u pls help me to rewrite the method with nested if statements? Thanks much.

```
isDiskMounted()
{   
    if [ -d "/folder1" ] && [ -d "/folder2" ] && [ -d "/folder3" ] && [ -d "/folder4" ];then
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false"
    fi
}
```

I try to write like this;

```
    isDiskMounted()
    {
        if [ -d "/folder1" ]; then
        echo "/folder1 klasoru bulundu" 
            if [ -d "/folder2" ]; then
        echo "/folder2 klasoru bulundu"  
                if [ -d "/folder3" ]; then
        echo "/folder3 klasoru bulundu" 
                    if [ -d "/folder4" ]; then
        echo "/folder4 klasoru bulundu" 
fi 
fi 
fi  
    echo "true"
    else
    echo "false"    
            fi
    }
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: They're spelled "you" and "please".  While a large percentage of people here are "guys", we also have females, mushrooms, ghosts, and an assortment of gravatars. Please explain in your question what is wrong and what you think it should look like (or desire to change).

Comment: Agree with @Murphy. The answer is a 5 word websearch away (3 words of which are in the name of the function!), that would have taken less effort than making the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purely from a code review point-of-view, I'd write that function like this:

```
func()
{
    for d in /folder1 /folder2 /folder3 /folder4 ; do
        if ! [ -d "$d" ] ; then
            echo "$d does not exist (or is not a directory)"
            return 1
        fi
    done
    echo "all dirs exist"
}
```

The loop might make it more straightforward to add new directories to the list, or pass them as arguments to the function.

(But if your aim is to check that something is mounted, like the function name implies, testing that directories exist doesn't do that much good.)

Comment: Actually your loop is better than an nested if statement. The name of the method is not a big issue. You did exactly what i need. Thanks much. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

To help you understand what's wrong with your attempt (and you don't tell us what fails and what you expect, relying on us to *guess*), I just changed the indentation of your code, formatting it in a way that reflects the execution paths:

```
isDiskMounted()
{
    if [ -d "/folder1" ]; then
        echo "/folder1 klasoru bulundu" 
        if [ -d "/folder2" ]; then
            echo "/folder2 klasoru bulundu"  
            if [ -d "/folder3" ]; then
                echo "/folder3 klasoru bulundu" 
                if [ -d "/folder4" ]; then
                    echo "/folder4 klasoru bulundu" 
                fi 
            fi 
        fi  
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false"    
    fi
}
```

Comment: Actually it is my first month on programing and first question on a coding q&a platform. And this indentation is really good. Thx for that. I am expecting all conditions return true on same time and will echo "true" at the end. But the problem is with my version it echo true if only first condition true, not even check rest ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so bad I can't help but to join this contest.

Here's my take on its interpratation.

```
checkDirectories() {
    # a logical switch variable for "all directories positive"
    allOk=true
    # as long as there are some arguments
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do    
        # if not -d, report and change the all-switch
        [ ! -d "$1" ] && echo Fail: "$1" && allOk=false
        # get rid of the first function argument,
        # so that "$2" becomes the new "$1" 
        shift
    done
    # if all ok, report this. otherwise return negative. 
    $allOk && echo "All directories present." || return 1
}
```

The function `checkDirectories` takes in directories as arguments (on the command line, in a script, etc). Unlike [ikkachu's one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419362/181255), it does not return on the first missing directory, but will go over all the list. If all the directories are ok, it will print:

```
All directories present.
```

Otherwise, if any directory is missing, it will report this fact (and for each other missing one):

```
Fail: directory_name/etc
```

At the end a negative result will be returned in this case.

Now follows a demonstration of this function in a directory with subdirectory `bin`, but no subdirectory `asdf`.

```
$ checkDirectories bin asdf
Fail: asdf
$ echo $?
1
$ checkDirectories bin
All directories present.
$ echo $?
0
```

Because the directory names are not hard-wired into the function, you can use it with different lists of directories. This includes lists of variable length. (So you can check four, or ten directories, as well as just one.)

I hope my answer helps you ask better questions in the future.